# Alter column schema of PGSQL not working while alter comment with YIi2

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, yii2, database-migration

```
$string = 'User name';
 $default = null; 

Simply from my traits , 
 self::integer()->comment($string)->defaultValue($default)
```

where $string is 'word' and $default is 'NULL' right now. 
 I have extended SchemaBuilderTrait from **/yiisoft/yii2/db/** .

When i am ,

```
echo self::integer()->comment($string)->defaultValue($default) ;
```

It result me like , Alter Table User

```
Alter column "userid" TYPE Integer NULL.
```

But it should return result me ,

```
ALTER TABLE "user" ALTER COLUMN "userid" TYPE integer COMMENT "user name";
```

It works with PHP **5.5.9** in **window** / **linux** both but not working with **5.6.21** and even It works with MYSQL in PHP 5.6.21 but not with PGSQL in same PHP version.

// My custom trait code :

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\SchemaBuilderTrait;

trait AbstractSchemaBuilderTrait 
{
    use SchemaBuilderTrait; 
 public function many2one($table,$column,$rel_table,$rel_column,$type,$size=null,$string=null,$default=null,$act_delete=null,$act_update=null)
    {
        if ($type == 'integer') {
            return self::integer()->comment($string)->defaultValue($default)."  ,ADD CONSTRAINT fk_$table"."_$column FOREIGN KEY($column)  REFERENCES $rel_table($rel_column)";
        }
        return self::$type($size)->comment($string)->defaultValue($default)."  ,ADD CONSTRAINT fk_$table"."_$column FOREIGN KEY($column)  REFERENCES $rel_table($rel_column)";
    }
}
?>
```

Can anyone Help for this ?

Comment: can u pls show your configuration file code ?

Comment: in main.php configuration everything working fine. 
but from my migration script or Upgrade module script , when i am going to alter schema from my custom trait ( see code structure on my question )


I am surprised that same code working fine with mysql in all version of yii & php but same code doesn't work with PGSQL on php 5.6.21 with yii 2.0.9 and its work with php 5.5.9 with yii 2.0.6 .

i hope you understood about issue. 
on question , i updated with code block and expected result and right now coming result .

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
$this->addCommentOnColumn('{{%tablename}}', 'columname', 'My New Comment');
```

This is only [available as of Yii 2.0.8](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-migration.html#addCommentOnColumn()-detail) though.

Comment: It's not fisible as this not an proper solution. What if there are 500 columns within just 30 tables. 
So not an solution to do for each specially.
Need some dynamic way

Comment: Yes . @Akkikodwani is right. that's my concern. so during migration process i am just altering comment.

$this->addCommentOnColumn('{{%tablename}}', 'columname', 'My New Comment'); is used for add comment against column but i don't have to add comment but need to alter column dynamically for all columns of all tables. same code also used for Module upgrade process from backend so Have to make it kind of generic.